# Stanford NERtagger output format

Tags: python

```
import os

os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "C:/Users/Anon/Desktop/ZAHID/Python/stanford-ner-2017-06-09/stanford-ner-2017-06-09/stanford-ner.jar"
os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = "C:/Users/Anon/Desktop/ZAHID/Python/stanford-ner-2017-06-09/stanford-ner-2017-06-09/classifiers/"

os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java.exe"


from nltk.tag.stanford import NERTagger

st = NERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz')

text = st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
print(text)

Output: [(u'Rami', u'PERSON'), (u'Eid', u'PERSON'), (u'is', u'O'), (u'studying', u'O'), (u'at', u'O'), (u'Stony', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'Brook', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'University', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'in', u'O'), (u'NY', u'O')]
```

But I want the output as :

```
[('Rami', 'PERSON'), ('Eid', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('studying', 'O'),
('at', 'O'), ('Stony', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Brook', 'ORGANIZATION'),
('University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'O'), ('NY', 'LOCATION')]
```

Comment: You mean why `NY` is not tagged `LOCATION` ?

Comment: please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No, I want to know , why my output has an extra 'u' such as (u'Rami', u'PERSON')

Comment: That means `unicode` , see document for unicode in python.

Comment: Is this a problem, to have unicode format in output?